# How should I wire this ceiling light pendant?

Tags: wiring, ceiling

I'm installing a light pendant.  Its wires are white, green, black.

My ceiling box has wires that are white, green, red.

I've attached white-white, green-green, black-red.

two questions: 
1) assuming black and red go together, is this correct?
2) green-green is secured by wire nut, bypassing green screw.  Or should both be wound to the green screw?

addendum: 
I had a leftover 6 inch red wire (from a previous endeavor) so I stripped it till it was bare, and used this to wind to both ground wires (from source and pendant) into the wire nut and then attached the other end of the bare wire to the green screw.

Comment: Greens should have a pigtail going to the screw.

Answer (score 1):

Both black and red are typically used to indicate hot.  Though you can't be positive without actually testing it with a multimeter.  Red is usually used when there are two hots (14/3 wire instead of 14/2).

Both green and bare copper are used to indicate ground.

So it sounds like you wired it correctly.  The green wire from the line (source) should also be attached to the green grounding screw in the electrical box.

Comment: thanks steven, I had a leftover 6 inch red wire (from a previous endeavor) so I stripped it till it was bare, and used this to wind to both ground wires (from source and pendant) into the wire nut and then attached the other end of the bare wire to the green screw.